# How to create workflow diagram with Angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, flowchart, flow-diagram

i need to build a workflow diagram with the given json object
json object has : label, from, to , nodeType for each node

```
{
    "name": "S1",
    "id": 492,
    "type": "start",
    "label": "Start",
    "level": "0",
    "isActive": true,
    "target": [
       {
        "id": 2
       }
     ]
   }
```

here is the diagram that should be done :
[workflow diagram sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUCs7.png)

tried to find any library doing this but i failed

Answer (score 0):

You can try PrimeNG's Org Chart, you can possibly get something close to what you required.

[Prime NG](https://primeng.org/organizationchart)

Comment: I checked it but it goes only in one direction from up to down